# How do I effectively make the main thread wait for Javafx Mouse Click

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am working on a Chess game in JavaFx and I have gotten to the first part of player interaction where I must detect which chess 'piece' the player selects.
After researching for 3-4 days on how to handle mouse click in Javafx I have found the solution to be akin to the sort of,

```
scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        //code here
    }
});
```

Although this block of code works for detecting mouse click and handling it, my program does not run exactly as I intend.
 [image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zslt.jpg)

As you can see from the output of the program in the photo above, the println "Passed" gets called before the program waits for the mouseclick event, which prints out the x location of the mouse.

So I was wondering, how can I make the rest of the program wait for a user for a mouse event?

My attempts:
I have tried a while loop where I looped the addEventHandler listener until the getX value was of a certain value, but when I had implemented the while loop my scene would not render, the scene would just be white.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Don't _wait for_ the event, instead _react to_ the event. This is known as [event-driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). You'll probably want to research the [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) as well.

Comment: Also, never infinitely loop on the _JavaFX Application Thread_. If you need a game loop then look into using `AnimationTimer` or `Timeline`. However, I don't think a game loop is necessary to implement chess as everything is driven by user interaction. This may be helpful: [Introduction to JavaFX for Game Development](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835).

Comment: I wrote a Tic-Tac-Toe (Noughts and Crosses) game many years ago; you can look at how that works if it helps. https://github.com/james-d/TicTacToe

Comment: Thank you for the responses Slaw and James_D, I will do my research on event-driven programming and the other links you provided, and will happily read through your tictactoe implementation. Much appreciated.